# How to select a day in Angular Calendar package

Tags: angular, angular-calendar

I am using Angular Calendar (see demos here https://mattlewis92.github.io/angular-calendar/#/kitchen-sink)

And I need to apply a different class to a day (or more) that I select.
So, if I click on a day (or more), I need them to be pink or something.

I have done something similar with today cell

```
const today_cell: 'today-cell' = 'today-cell';

export class MonthCalendarComponent implements OnInit {

  todayCssClass: string = today_cell;

 beforeMonthViewRender({ body }: { body: CalendarMonthViewDay[] }): void {
       body.forEach(day => {
         if (day.isToday === true) {
            day.cssClass = this.todayCssClass;
          }
     }
}
```

but I am not using click event. How can I do it?

Comment: Do you want to make the days selectable, or just apply different formatting on each day you clicked once, without doing anything with those days afterwards?

Comment: After I selected some days, I will send them to database, so I need to save them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a live demo in the Component you linked to, doing exactly what you need to do. Selecting multiple days and coloring them in pink, with full code and as mentioned a demo:
https://mattlewis92.github.io/angular-calendar/#/selectable-period

There's a predefined css class `.cal-day-selected` which is used to color the selected days and in the demo the selected days are inside an array `selectedDays: any = [];`

Comment: I need to show week name in calendar  in short like  Monday = mo, Tuesday = Tu.                           Please give some idea how to do it.